# How to remove the “x people like this” link in Facebook

Tags: facebook-pages

I would like to know how I can remove the link on the text "x people like this" that I see on many business pages

Answer (score 1):

- [noscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) with firefox
- [Notscript](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn) with google chrome

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your response. I’m still a bit fuzzy on the answer.  In other words I cannot remove the physical link set on the “X people like this” link on the fan page on Facebook where it exists, I have to change my own browser settings?  Won't others still see this link if they view my Facebook business fan page account on their own browsers?

Comment: Yes other will still see the link. No as far as I know you can not remove that link from a Facebook page on facebook.com its self.